# Symfony 1.4, sfGuardPlugin with existing user table/model

Tags: symfony1

I have symfony 1.4 installed and had setup my own user model (table). Now, in order to use sfFacebookConnectPlugin, it asks to use sfGuard plugin, so it can easily integrate existing users with facebook account.

Is there a way to use sfGuardPlugin with existing user model ?
OR 
is there a better way to implement facebook connect, such that it recognizes the same user (by email), if exists, or creates a new user in the user table with the fb email id and also creates the session.

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sfGuardPlugin with an existing model, the schema file will be loaded from the plugin's folder and the table names are namespaced in a way that prevents naming collisions.

All you have to do is install the plugin as per its installation instructions and then build your model. To deploy to production you can either copy the SQL that propel generates (in data/sql) and execute it or use a program like Toad for MySQL to generate diff sql upgrade scripts.

Have you tried and failed? I hope I've addressed your concerns.

Comment: Thanks Juan, I was reading the sfGuard plugin instructions and thats what concerned me since it said it would create its own table. I'll still try to install it and see if it can read from existing model and use the existing user table. I'll update here with my findings

Comment: As long as you're using version control and some sort of dev/staging environment then you should have no problem testing :)

Comment: Yes, I was able to use it with existing user table, by adding some additional code to update when User was updated.